# Apache2 return php source code

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu

I installed Apache2 in my Xubunt, but I have a problem, When I see a Html file it works but when I see a Php file, Apache shows my sources code and I don't see my site and my script don't works.

See my desktop:

[image]

Comment: Did you also install PHP in your Xubunt? e.g. LAMP ?

Comment: @SLWS yes ,when i insert php -v in terminal that say
PHP 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies

Comment: Which version of php you using. Need to ensure you enable the php mod. assuming php 7 `sudo a2enmod php7.0`

Comment: @JasonJoslin 
i use php 7.0.15
i enter this command in terminal 
but when restart my apache terminal say:
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: And what does those commands shows? It seems that php mod is not installed or properly configured.

Comment: @Zefiryn php is install maby problem in configure and what must i do?

Comment: Try installing libapache2-mod-php7.0. This package should get all scripts. If it is installed or won't help check logs in /var/log/apache2/* to see what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing libapache2-mod-php7.0. This package should get all scripts. If it is installed or won't help check logs in /var/log/apache2/* to see what is the problem. –

Answer (score 0):

try on `sudo apt-get install php-pear php5-suhosin`

Comment: It would be helpful if you included in your answer why php-pear and suhosin might be necessary.